# Grub can't find kernel when booting Lubuntu

Tags: grub2, kernel, lubuntu

I have an old PC I haven't used for about 10 years. It has Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows installed. I wanted to install Lubuntu on it and be able to use grub to choose what to boot into.

I installed Lubuntu 20.04 LTS and installation was fine. I have 3 disks on the PC and Ubuntu and Lubuntu are on /dev/sdc. When I first installed Lubuntu, there was no entry in grub for it. I then ran boot-repair and it added some entries.  For example:

`Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os 'gnulinux-simple-xxxxxxxxxsome-guidxxxxxx (on dev/sda8)`

When I tried to select the above, I get this:

`error: file not found.`
`error: you need to load the kernel first`

I'm not sure what kind of diagnostic info would be helpful.

Edit: Ran `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` and got the following output.  Notice there is no new Linux kernel listed:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows XP Professional on /dev/sdc1
done
```

Answer (score -3):

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Update your grub file it should solve that issue.

Comment: boot ubuntu and run that command? I ran that command without update to see the output before but I didn't see it point to the Lubuntu partition. There might be some weird setup with my MBR that's causing this.

Comment: You need to use sudo first if you think it still not detected you can cat out to see the file try reinstalling grub or grub2.

Comment: I ran with sudo and here is the output.  Notice the linux kernels are all really old:
```Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows XP Professional on /dev/sdc1
done
```

Comment: If you're wondering what's happening with the votes: **Manually updating the GRUB files using `grub-mkconfig` are highly discouraged**, one should use the `sudo update-grub` command instead. Moreover, updating the GRUB files won't help in this case, so, your answer is incorrect and is downvoted as such.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how to fix it?